# yum HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden behind NAT on AWS

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-web-services, nat, yum

I had some weird issues while trying to run `yum update` on a centos 7 server on AWS behind an instance NAT.

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=genclo error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden


One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Now trying with curl from the instance that I use as a NAT instance I get the correct response:

`curl -vvv 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=genclo`

```
http://mirror.strencom.net/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.vooservers.com/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://centos.serverspace.co.uk/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/mirror.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
 http://mirror.vorboss.net/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/
```

The date is correct so I'm very confused now. And I'm starting to consider moving to AWS Linux.

Thanks for you help :)

UPDATE: I used an EIP to the same instance and yum is working so I guess its an NAT issue. I still don't understand why.

Comment: What does your routing table in your VPC look like?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I don't have a network issue here because I can connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Error 403 is http response code and is not related to IP (Layer 3) routing/NAT issues.
Possible reasons:

1. Something's wrong in your NAT instance configuration
2. You are using Layer 7 reverse proxy (check proxy variables, yum.conf
   etc)
3. You are using transparent proxy server
4. mirrorlist.centos.org really doesn't like you :)

Answer (score 0):

For internet access to work behind a NAT instance, your *default route* in your private subnets needs to be the *internal* ENI of your NAT instance - see [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#nat-routing-table).

Also, your NAT EC2 instance needs to have the **Source/Destination Check** disabled - see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck). I would also make sure you have followed and understood the [Amazon documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) on using a NAT EC2 instance.

For ease of use, I would recommend using an [AWS NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), which provides the same functionality as an EC2 instance, without the hassle of setting up the OS firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but actually the network is fine . I can connect to internet with NATed subnet. But I still get 403 if I hit the repository server.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. It was related to the policy of the s3 vpc endpoint (since we've an s3 endpoint the traffic doesn't go through the NAT).

Change it to something like (adjust bucket names as needed)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::amazonlinux.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::amazonlinux-2-repos-ap-southeast-2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Articles with more information:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-troubleshoot-yum-errors-al1-al2/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-access.html#update-vpc-endpoint-policy